# mysql Innodb tables taking more than 4 hours to optimize

Tags: mysql, optimization, innodb

There were few InnoDB MySQL tables fragmented in the databases.

When I am trying to optimize, it's taking more than 4 hours and still in progress of optimization.

I am using optimize table command to this.

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Priya

Comment: Why `OPTIMIZE`??  InnoDB mostly takes care of fragmentation without explicit action.  How much did it shrink the table?  Did you have `innodb_file_per_table` set?

Comment: @RickJames , innodb_file_per_table is already set for all tables. I used optimize to take action for fragmentation. Was not aware of the fact that InnodB takes care of fragmentation without explicit action. Also when I tried to optimize, after 4 hours also it was still in progress state, so ultimately I killed the process. Please suggest.

Comment: How big is the table; must be quite large to take 4+ hours.  `OPTIMIZE` will eventually finish.  The table might shrink in half, but then quickly re-grow as you `INSERT/UPDATE` into it.  Because of the regrowth, `OPTIMIZE` is (usually) futile.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `OPTIMIZE TABLE` use `ALTER TABLE ENGINE INNODB` with `[pt-online-schema-change][1]`. It will still take four+ hours, but at least it won't block writes to the table.

Comment: sure thing. Thanks